# Run a script for a specified period of time in Java

Tags: java

I have a java code which I want to run. If the job does not complete within, say, 2 hours, then it should be killed automatically (basically, some kind of timed batch).

How to achieve this in Java?

Comment: @LutzHorn - I have looked for options , but came across only scheduling jobs which runs jobs at a specific time (also possibly after regular intervals). However , what I need is a timed batch that stops executing after a set interval of time.

Comment: You write code in your job logic to check how long it's been running, then abort if time limit has been exceeded, e.g. by throwing an exception. I don't see the problem, and it's not like we can do it, since we don't have ***your*** code.

Comment: @Andreas -  I am not asking anyone to change my code. All I wanted to know if there is any API for this (like there is Timer and and TimerTask to schedule jobs). Thanks

Comment: Many of the executors in `java.util.concurrent` include options for supplying timeouts. For example, `executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)` will block until all tasks have complete or 2 hours have passed.

Comment: @sprinter That cancels the wait, it doesn't stop the asynchronous processing you're waiting on.

Comment: @Andreas you would need to follow it with a `executorService.shutdownNow()` to kill any tasks.

Comment: Question, what is the process doing ? Is it possible to manage the timeout in your code or is it stuck on one line the all time ? If this is the later, you won't be able to do much in java.

Comment: @Akashjain 1) Your question isn't asking for an API. --- 2) Your question says nothing about scheduled job. --- 3) To have the "java code which you want to run" stop running after a certain amount of time, the code has to stop itself, by occationally checking for timeout. There are many ways to track timeout, I mentioned one on previous comment.

Comment: @sprinter Javadoc of `shutdownNow()`: ***Attempts** to stop all actively executing tasks*, ... *There are **no guarantees** beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via `Thread.interrupt()`, so any task that fails to respond to interrupts **may never terminate**.* --- In short, to make sure a task stops running, **the task has to be coded for it**. Besides, question says nothing about using `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @AxelH - The process is used to make a db call to purge some huge tables.
The process has 2 paths to complete - 
a) If the purge completes within , say 2 hours, and returns the control.
or
b) The process is killed (automatically) 2 hours later if it does not finish. No manual intervention.
Also , this cannot be a async call. The process must wait for 2 hours if the purge is running long.

Comment: best approach IMO is, as suggested by Andreas, have the process itself check and terminate after timeout - DB access can be blocked and killing such can cause the DB session to stay alive until it gets a timeout, leaving tables locked

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Java 9 or higher, you can do the timeout batching as below:-

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::longRunningTask)
                       .orTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
 future.get(); // j.u.c.ExecutionException after waiting for 2 second
```

If it completes within the `timeout` limit, it will return the value (here an `Integer` object in response to `future.get()` method)

And, this batching is **asynchronous** (If you don't call get method explicitly.)

**NOTE:** This does not prevent the thread from completing the task, it just completes a future in main thread with a Timeout Exception so that main thread can continue. The background task/thread is still continues to finish. (look @Andreas comment)

**Some Samples:-**

```
final CompletableFuture<Void> future =
                   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::longRunningTask)
                                    .orTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

future.get(); // j.u.c.ExecutionException after waiting for 2 second
```

And the `longRunningTask()` :-

```
private Void longRunningTask(){
    log.info("Thread name" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        log.info("Going to sleep for 10 sec...");
        Thread.sleep(10*1000);
        log.info("Sleep Completed. Task Completed.");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.info("Exception Occurred");
    }
    finally{
        log.info("Final Cleanup in progress.");
    }
    log.info("Finishing the long task.");
    return null;
}
```

If you run above code, it will give Execution Exception in main thread (where `future.get()` is called) but the `longRunningTask` will still print `Sleep Completed. Task Completed.` after completing 10 sec sleep.

If you carefully notice, the `longRunnigThread` is never interrupted (does not enter in catch block) so continues normally, but main thread gets an exception on `get()`.

**Workaround/Solution:**

Use `ExecutorService` and submit the longRunnigTask future with this `Exceutor`, if timeout occurs, shutdown the executor or else, shutdown after successful `get()` in case of no timeout exception.

**Sample:**

```
    ExecutorService myWorkers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    final CompletableFuture<Void> longTask = 
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::longRunningTask, myWorkers)
                .orTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    try {
        longTask.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        log.info("EE... Kill the executor thread/s.");
        myWorkers.shutdownNow(); // this will interrupt the thread, catch the IntrExcep in thread and return the execution there
    }
```

and the slightly modified `longRunnigTask`

```
private Void longRunningTask(){
    log.info("Thread name" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    try {
        log.info("Going to sleep for 10 sec...");
        Thread.sleep(10*1000);
        log.info("Sleep Completed. Task Completed.");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.info("Exception Occurred");
        return null; // this will finish the thread exce releasing all locking resources. Can be GCed then.
    }
    finally{
        log.info("Final Cleanup in progress.");
    }
    log.info("Finishing the long task.");
    return null;
}
```

With this approach, it won't complete the task inf timeout is occurred (you won't see `Sleep completed. Task completed.` in logs..), and would see, `exception occurred` in the `longRunningTask` thread (because of interrupt caused by `myWorker.shutdown`).

Comment: That completes the Future, it doesn't stop the thread doing the asynchronous processing.

Comment: @Andreas are you talking about `get` method or `orTimeOut` method??

Comment: I'm referring to the *effect* of `orTimeout`, which happens during the `get` call, so .... both?

Comment: I couldn't get you correctly, could you please share any reference for it? I'm looking into the docs from here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#orTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: @miiiii -- after 10 seconds completes, the flow returns to the main program (i.e. future gets completed) , but the async task does not get killed.

Comment: @miiiii What do you think a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) is? Since you seem to know your javadocs, you should already know that it says (as the very first thing): *"A `Future` represents the **result** of an asynchronous computation"*. It does not represent the asynchronous *computation*, just the result. So when `orTimeout` says *"Exceptionally completes this CompletableFuture"*, it means that it mark the `CompletableFuture` **result object** as timed out, but doesn't in any way do anything to cancel the asynchronous computation.

Comment: Much better, but the interrupt only works because the long running task called a method that is interrupt-aware (`sleep`). A real long running task might be in a CPU intensive loop, and might not be calling any interrupt-aware methods, so the interrupt would be ignored. Such a long running task has to be coded to be interrupt-aware, by periodically checking, using `if (Thread.interrupted())`. In short, for a long running task to fully support timeout, if much be coded for it. Some tasks might get that support "for free", but you'd have to analyze the code and add interrupt checks as needed.